# Validate a couple of fields aren't duplicate

Tags: c#, wcf

How to validate a couple of fields from the front end that call the service isn't a duplicate value in the database?

I have a WCF Service that is being called by Mule. Mule passes me an object, where I need to check there are two fields that are not duplicated. (Meaning, no same values for those fields exist in the DB and if exists throw an error saying its duplicated).

Please let me know how to do this validation in the WCF Service. I need to ensure, "EmpID" and "Reference" aren't duplicated.

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmpID { get; set;}
  public string Reference { get ; set ;}
  public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You could use a primary key for EmpID and a unique index for Reference, then if the insert fails you know one of them isn't unique. Another alternative - especially if you want to show easily _which_ is a duplicate - is to do a select on the table for the new values to see if they already exist.

Comment: @stuartd: that's a brilliant point, thank you for the insights. I am afraid I already have a primary key on a column in the table, so I dont know if I can make it as a composite primary key altering the table. Is it a good idea? Also, your unique key constraint is a good idea for the reference column, I can make it. Your 2nd option sounds great, you mean create a method to do select query in WCF/data layer and use ExecuteScalar for that column? If that exists then return error?

Comment: What database engine are you using?  Because a merge statement on itself with the parameters would allow you to insert if not matched, if matched update.  Also, you could use inserted.* with an output to see the newly created data.

Comment: @Greg: SQL Server 2005 :) Old one I know

Comment: You can still use the database engine to ensure it does not exists before inserting and seeing if a record row was inserted.

Comment: @stuartd: Something like this? SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE ([user] = @user)" , conn);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtBox_UserName.Text);
int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

if(UserExist > 0)
{
   //Username exist
}
else
{
   //Username doesn't exist.
}

Comment: @Learner something like that, yes.

Comment: I would make one change though, `if(int.TryParse(..., out int exists) && exists > 0)` to avoid the parse having an issue and combine into a single line.

Comment: @stuartd: Thank you So much.

Comment: @Greg: Uhmmm thank you,

Comment: @Learner I would try to upgrade to 2008 or higher, better performance, security, and flexibility.  Then you could do items such as merge.  Which would be helpful.

Comment: @Greg: Jesus, I just spoke that with my colleague, but its not my decision although I wish to be the IT boss but unfortunately a programmer that can't make voice in a large scale company. Everyone know MS support also not there for SQL 2005, but we have to do with it for now :|

Comment: @Learner Bummer, some of those hurdles will become pain point.  I hear ya though.  You might be able to justify 2017 or 2019 now that MSSQL can run in Linux.  So you can save some server cost by using a Linux server, but if they're running 2005 SQL I imagine the OS is likely equally as old.

Comment: @Greg: Agreed, lol a layman don't have voice, although I am a management execute by skillset and innate skills, I always wished I was in that position. Programming is only 2nd and or last option for me, but I do lol and hence would have changed it if I were a boss.

Comment: @stuartd: Going through few more on the google, how about adding both those columns as a new unique constraint? Do you see any problem in that? Your opinion please?

Comment: @Learner You should be okay, but you need to make sure that those two keys together will always be unique and cannot be a duplicate, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @Greg: uhmmm okay :S lol

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by doing a SELECT into the DB, if it returns 0 rows, it means that there's no duplicated values... Depending on your need, it will be necessary to do multiple SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation on `{ set: }`

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmpID { get; set;}
  public string Reference { get ; set{
      if(value == this.EmpID)
          throw new Exception("Email and Reference can't be same!");
  } }
  public string Name { get; set;}
}
```